# MongoDB tree structure using $graphLookup spanning multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm starting out with MongoDB and I'm trying to build a tree structure of objects stored in different collections. I know how many levels the hierarchy runs deep, so recursion is not a problem.

Each level of the tree is stored in a different collection (for reasons out of my control), so I have to start from `Collection_A`, getting all children in `Collection_B`, then getting all children of elements from `Collection_B` in `Collection_C`. Each item in `Collection_B` has the `_id` of its parent from `Collection_A`, each item in `Collection_C` has the `$_id` of its parent from `Collection_B`.
Also, each item has only one parent, but can have zero, one or many children.

How can I get all children and grandchildren of an element in `Collection_A`?
I know how to use `$graphLookup` to get children in `Collection_B`, but how do I go deeper? I think my problem is referencing the `$_id` field for each element in the array of children.

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uIWP_mk75xm) is a link to mongoplayground with the basic structure of my collections and what I tried to do.

EDIT: with help from @Hussam I got a bit further, but I realize my post was not clear enough.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "key_A": "value_a1"
    "children_A": [
      {
        "_id": 11,
        "id_A": 1,
        "key_B": "value_b2",
        "children_B": [
          {
            "_id": 103,
            "id_B": 11,
            "key_C": "value_c4"
          },
          {
            "_id": 102,
            "id_B": 11,
            "key_C": "value_c3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": 10,
        "id_A": 1,
        "key_B": "value_b1",
        "children_B": [
          {
            "_id": 101,
            "id_B": 10,
            "key_C": "value_c2"
          },
          {
            "_id": 100,
            "id_B": 10,
            "key_C": "value_c1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some mistake in your existing pipeline. Your `startWith` in second stage was not a variable.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/uIWP_mk75xm

In response to your edit, heres what you need to do to put it inside collection A objects

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tl8yWeTM26i

Comment: Thanks! I'm still struggling a bit with syntax. Is it possible to have ``children_B`` in each of ``children_A`` items? I'm editing the original question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Yes definately possible. Post the final result structure you want.

Comment: Updated the original question with the structure I'd like, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have a lot to learn, it did not occur to me I could use ``group`` to achieve this result.